# How to modify a lambda pointer capture?

Tags: c++, lambda

So what i want to do is just modify the x value passed in the parameter.

```
class B
{
public:
    void DoSomething(function<void()> func)
    {
        func();
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    void Start(B* b, int* x)
    {
        auto func = [&x]()->void
        {
            x++;
            cout << x;
        };
        b->DoSomething(func);
    }
};
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations, but it just wont work.
If the x value was a valuetype and not a pointer, then it would work.

Comment: What doesn't work, and how? Do you really want to modify `x`, `*x`, or whatever lvalue is passed to `Start`? Maybe expand it to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Oh, i actually wanted to modify the (*x), NO_NAME answered it correctly for me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is still a pointer inside the lambda.

Code bellow should work.

```
auto func = [&x]()->void
{
    (*x)++;
    cout << (*x);
};
```

Capture by reference means you can modify value of original `x` but it is not changing type of the variable.
If you are capturing the variable by reference, you can set address which is pointed by `x`. This is because you have a reference to the original pointer inside lambda. When you capture `x` by value, you create copy of it.